# Unable to configure rHive for HDP2.4 Sandbox

Tags: r, ant, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

### Problem

I have hortonworks sandbox 2.4 on virtual box. I am following the tutorial found [here](http://toodey.com/2016/01/14/install-rhadoop-rhdfs-and-rmr2-on-hortonworks-sandbox/) for installing rHive on the sandbox. I am unable to duplicate steps 4 and 6 without producing errors. They are as follows:

Step 4 Error: Being in the `~/RHive/` directory and using `ant build` gives me the following error:

`BUILD FAILD /root/RHive/build.xml:39: /root/RHive/usr/hdp/current/hive-server2/lib does not exist`

Step 6 Error: Using `R CMD INSTALL RHive_2.0-0.10.tar.gz` produces the following error:

`ERROR: dependencies "rJava", "Rserve" are not available for package "RHive"`

### Attempts

I have followed the directions as specified on here as well, which is the Rhive documents, but unfortunately have gotten nowhere.

Step 4: I am at a loss as to why ant build could be failing. I have verified I installed it correctly and it states `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled April 9 2016` when I run command `ant -version`. So I followed those procedures correctly.

Step 6: 
I used rStudio to install `rJava` and `Rserve` using `install.package()` command. Indeed, the tutorial suggests this as well. I suspect something is wrong with my java dependencies?

I have used Ambari to use Hive before, but this is the first time I am trying to use it in R and I am abviously still new to the hortonworks vm, so I would appreciate any kindness and assistance to help me fix the issues I am encountering.

Comment: I managed to install RHive in a Hortonworks cluster following this instructions https://github.com/nexr/RHive. Did you set the HIVE_HOME and HADOOP_HOME variables? Did you install the RUnit package?

Comment: I did all of those things. Was your VM 2.4? I think folks before 2.3 haven't reported any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is to abandon rHive. It was yanked from CRAN. Anyone thinking about using it with R and finds this post, please consider RJDBC.